# Been trying to set Custom time on a file using Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to set the Custom time attribute in firebase on the front end. Everything is possible to set, like contentDisposition, custom Metadata etc, just can't find any way or any info about setting Custom time.

You can see it referenced here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#custom-time

You can set the custom time on the file manually in the Storage cloud console, but even when you do and you load the file in firebase on the front end, it's missing from the returned object! (makes me feel like it's not possible to achieve this)

```
var storage = this.$firebase.app().storage("gs://my-files");
var storage2 = storage.ref().child(this.file);

//// Tried this
var md = {
    customTime: now.$firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
};

//// & Tried this
var md = {
    Custom-Time: now.$firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
};

storage2.updateMetadata(md).then((metadata) => {
    console.log(metadata);                     
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err); 
});
```

The reason I ask is I'm trying to push back the lifecycle delete date (which will be based on the custom time) every time the file is loaded. Does anyone know the answer or an alternative way of doing it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The CustomTime metadata is not possible to update using Firebase JavaScript SDK since it is not included in the file metadata [properties list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata#file_metadata_properties) mentioned in the documentation. So even if you specify it as customTime: or Custom-Time: the updateMetadata() method does not perform any changes.

I suggest you as a better practice, [set the CustomTime metadata from the cloud console](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata) and modify the [CustomTimeBefore Lifecycle condition](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#customtimebefore) from the back-end each time you load the file using the [addLifeCycleRule method](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#addLifecycleRule) of the [GCP Node.js Client.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage)

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();
//Imports your Google Cloud Storage bucket
const myBucket = storage.bucket('my_bucket');

//-
// Delete object that has a customTime before 2021-05-25.
//-
myBucket.addLifecycleRule({
  action: 'delete',
  condition: {
    customTimeBefore: new Date('2021-05-25')
  }
}, function(err, apiResponse) {});
```